# Android How to Create Custom ActionBar with custom up button and custom background image

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm a beginner with Android. I want to create a custom actionbar for my app, with a custom background image and a custom up button, I have tried but result is not exactly like what I want. 
[My custom action bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnXtM.jpg) I want my custom background fit to screen. How can I do?
This is my custombar_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bar">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:text="SFlashCard"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in Main activity:

```
ActionBar actBar = getSupportActionBar();

actBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
actBar.setCustomView(customView);


actBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Many thanks for all support!

Comment: This is my background image: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgOTbBh_NAxcUxBVmlpQUJuSFE)

This is my target: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzgOTbBh_NAxZzk4aEVFWEZ0Wmc)

Comment: It'd probably be easier to use the v7 support `Toolbar` instead, rather than messing with a custom `View` on an `ActionBar`. A `Toolbar` is a `ViewGroup`, so you can put your `ImageView` and `TextView` inside it just like your are in the `LinearLayout` now. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742420/android-how-to-tutorial-for-changing-actionbar-to-actionbarcompat-toolbar), If you want to try it.

Comment: but Toolbar is not working with Android 4. and earlier

Comment: Should work all the way down to Android 2.1 (API level 7). https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat